# Using Intellij to set breakpoints in gradle project

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle

Now that IntelliJ 12.1 is out, I was hoping to be able to attach the debugger to a 'gradle run' app and have it stop at breakpoints.  I've tried both right-clicking run and choosing to debug it, and setting GRADLE_OPTS environment variables as suggested in this answer:

[Debug Gradle plugins with IntelliJ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11129401/debug-gradle-plugins-with-intellij)

and attaching the debugger remotely, which works fine, but neither one breaks on the breakpoints.  I must be missing something.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I can debug remotely by configuring the `run` task. Since it is a [JavaExec](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.JavaExec.html) task, it supports jvmArgs properties:

```
run {
    jvmArgs "-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=5005"
}
```

and debug properties:

```
run {
    debug true
}
```

Right clicking to debug doesn't seem to work because IntelliJ is attaching the debugger to the wrong JVM i.e. gradle.

Comment: Great!  That works.  For bonus points and eternal gratitude, is there a way to chain starting the run task and attaching the remote debugger, any idea?

Comment: I'm [afraid](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12454891/2464295) [no](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3823346/2464295), [because](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4558818/2464295) it's a child process.

Comment: Quick tips, you can use gradle property (-P) and make the build.gradle read the property to enable the debug e.g. if hasProperty -> debug true

Comment: Your solution is still valid. There had been some difficulties for me, however, getting it to work with the last versions of IntelliJ and Gradle using a debugging task. I've created a new post for it, if you're interested: http://stackoverflow.com/q/42748377/3767398

Comment: I am not quite familiar with Gradle. I have the same issue that I cannot debug from the Intellij. Where should I add this run jvmArgs? Is it possible to add it to run configuration of Intellij gradle run task?

Answer (score 2):

I can debug normally. I only can't debug if I use the gradle daemon ("--daemon" option).

Comment: I found that Intellij automatically passes the required jvmArgs, so disabling the daemon (so the process started with these jvmArgs actually executes the code) does the trick for me.

Comment: Use --no-daemon to one-off disable the daemon btw.

Comment: This argument does not work with the newest versions of IntelliJ anymore since it uses the Gradle Tooling API. There is no way to turn off the daemon.